# Chrome/OSX: Pink blotches on YouTube image

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube

The image below shows the problem.

I see the problem only when I view YouTube videos on my Mac and the browser is Chrome.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: Pink blotches]

Comment: This is a decoding issue. Are you running the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: @RandolphWest: yes, I am.

Comment: Are you viewing the video as HTML5 or Flash?

Answer (score 2):

First try selecting a different quality. 
If the issue persists with all versions of the video, update your graphics drivers, Flash and Chrome then restart your computer.