# Chrome : Pink patches on Youtube Video

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome/OSX: Pink blotches on YouTube image](https://superuser.com/questions/426524/chrome-osx-pink-blotches-on-youtube-image)

I am running OSX 10.6.8 and the lastest version of Chrome.  On a lot of my YouTube videos (using HTML5), I am seeing pink splotches on the video as it plays.  Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S. I know there is another thread on this already, but the original poster is not responding anymore and my attempts to get the conversation going again gets deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Well, we're not a forum, so if you posted an answer, asking for help, then that's the wrong way to go about it and your post was deleted for a good reason. Can you please link us to the question you're talking about? Also, knowing your specific Chrome version would be good.

Comment: Chrome Version: Version 20.0.1132.57
Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/426524/chrome-osx-pink-blotches-on-youtube-image

Thanks!

Comment: I see, well, it's the same question, so we'll need close it as a duplicate anyway. If you believe this is a bug, I would try to file a bug report in the Chromium issue tracker (and also check it with a more recent release of Chrome, maybe from the Beta or Dev channels).